# getting the properties/fields using java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a POJO with 6 properties as below. i need get only 5 field names using reflection.

```
class Employee {

private Long id;
private String address;
private String phone;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String designation;

//getters and setters

}
```

but i would like to get only 5 field names except 'phone' using java reflection getFields(). how can i get the field names? is it possible to get only specific field names instead of all field names from the pojo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the name of your field to `getField()` method: -

```
Class<Employee> aClass = Employee.class
Field field = aClass.getField("address");  // For public fields
```

but that will only fetch you `public fields`.

You can get `private fields`, by using `getDeclaredField("fieldName")`:

```
Field f = aClass.getDeclaredField("address"); //For all fields(Including private)
```

**UPDATE**: -

If you don't have field names, then you have to iterate through all the fields and filter the array using the field name manually by using `Field.getName()` method. There is no other way out: -

```
for(Field field: aClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (!field.getName().equals("phone")) {
        // Process it
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry..i need field names only.

Comment: @user1016403 So, you don't have `fields name`? For that check the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an API to "get all fields except".

Just get all fields and test for the field name you don't want and skip it in your processing.